# Change Kendo UI Upload control "drop your file here" message change

Tags: css, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I am trying to Use Drag and Drop facility provided by kendo ui upload.

[image]

In above picture, I am trying to get space between **button** and the **drop files here to upload** text.

I tried using padding and margin as below.

```
div.k-dropzone em {
  visibility: visible;
  color:black;
  font-size:12px;        
  margin-top:100px;
  padding-top:20%;
}
```

But none of it seems to be working. (margin-left works but margin-top didn't work)

Anyone has idea if we can do it or it is not possible.

Comment: Can you put code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or add HTML code after drop/drag form rendered

Comment: @HuyNguyen Here is the sample JSFiddle i am getting. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/zbmbLL3o/)  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your jsfiddle please check this link:-

https://jsfiddle.net/zbmbLL3o/1/

css for showing gap between button the text:-

```
.k-upload-button{
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
```